# Checking if Oracle.DataAccess Exists

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oracle, oracle11g

I want to check whether the correct version of the Oracle driver is installed and can be found before an application runs so I can display an error message and fail gracefully.  This is a C# windows forms application.

When I run the application on a machine that doesn't have the correct version of Oracle, I get the following message and the application is left in a hung state:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I reliably check if this assembly is available?

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar question today can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531475/oracle-dataaccess-dll-can-not-be-located-though-it-exists/8531874#8531874

Comment: I need to programatically check whether it exists at runtime, not check whether it is installed in general.  I was thinking there should be an easy way in .NET to do this, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Figured it out.  Did a try...catch on:

Assembly.Load("Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342");

Answer (score 0):

In addition yo your own answer, you could also do it in a general way (for all assembly loading issues) using the `AssemblyResolve` event. Here's an example:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, prms) => {
    Console.WriteLine("Could not load assembly \"{0}\".", prms.Name);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(1);

    return null;
};

Assembly.Load("this asembly does not exist");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories to achieve the same.
The sample code below can check it for you.

```
    private bool checkSpecifiedProviderExists()
    {
        var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"];  
        var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);    

        try
        {
            var dbConnection = factory.CreateConnection();
            if(dbConnection !=null) return true;
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
                return false;
        }
    }
```