# Could not load file or assembly Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, odp.net

I have an asp.net mvc (EF) project ,
I had downloaded oracle data provider with version 4.112.2.50 -32bit on my pc when moving project to windows server 2008 (I have the same version of odp-64bit) I have the below problem:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

when I toke Oracle the "Oracle.DataAccess.dll" from the server and make it with my project reference
I have another error message like the above with a file "Oracle.Web"

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.Web' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

also if I get the File "Oracle.Web.dll" to my project reference from the server I have the same error with "Oracle.Web"

Comment: Check the points mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531475/oracle-dataaccess-dll-can-not-be-located-though-it-exists/8531874#8531874. Most likely it's a 32/64 bit issue.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In the **IIS Manager** select your server and select "***Application Pools***". Select the application pool used by your Web App and click on "***Advanced Settings***" from the right hand menu.

In the "***General Section***" of the advanced Settings click on the "***Enable 32-bit Applications***" and set it to ***True***.

This fix only applies to 64-bit servers that attempt to execute the 32-bit version of the Oracle Dlls.

Regards
George

Answer (score 6):

George Wrote:

> In the IIS Manager select your server and select "Application Pools". Select the application pool used by your Web App and click on "Advanced Settings" from the right hand menu.
>
> In the "General Section" of the advanced Settings click on the "Enable 32-bit Applications" and set it to True.
>
> This fix only applies to 64-bit servers that attempt to execute the 32-bit version of the Oracle Dlls.

The opposite is also true. If you are **using the 64 bit version** of the Oracle Dlls then you must set "**Enable 32-bit Applications**" to **false**.

--Jacob

Comment: You are my internet <3

Answer (score 4):

1. Oracle.DataAccess.dll must be installed not only referenced.
2. Change the copy local property of the reference to true.

Comment: Oracle.DataAccess.dll is installed also I changed copy local for all references

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect Format indicates a bitness problem.  To get the server running change the application pool your program is running in to enable 32 bit support or install a 64 bit oracle client.

Answer (score 0):

Changing app pool from 64-bit to 32-bit is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting **bin** and **obj** folders solved my problem.