# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' (x64)

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a WCF service to host in IIS.
My production and development servers are 64 bit.
The WCF service needs to be able to connect to a several different Oracle databases based on the client request.

I am using Entity Framework 5 with ODAC, and with the DbContext Initialiser, I have the option of providing a database connection to use.

```
private void ExampleSelect(string dataSource, string user, string password)
{
    var connection =
        string.Format("DATA SOURCE={0};PASSWORD={1};USER ID={2}",
                          dataSource, password, user);

    using (var context = new OracleDbContext(new OracleConnection(connection)))
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

The problem I have lies with `new OracleConnection(connection)`.  To use this line, I need to reference the x64 version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll

When I come to publish, I get the warning:

> [image: warning]

and the error:

> [image: error]

The platform target for my project is currently 'Any CPU'. If I change this to target x64, I get the same error, but this time it refers to my project and not Oracle.DataAccess

> [image: error2]

Any of the above builds successfully on my development machine, I only get the errors when I come to publish.

What am I doing wrong here?

These solutions appear to be related, but they all refer to 32 bit Oracle Dlls:

[Could not load file or assembly Oracle.DataAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661749/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess?rq=1)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' 64 bit ODP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186661/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-64-bit-odp-net?rq=1)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-error?rq=1)

To rule it out, I have also tried installing both the 64bit and 32bit Oracle Clients on the development server, but I still don't get as far as even publishing so I'm not sure that the server is the cause of the problem.

The `Enable 32 bit Application` property on the Application pool in IIS does not make any difference, but I tried it anyway.

Comment: Check if in bin directory of online server there is an oracle.dataaccess.dll

Comment: The point is that I cannot publish to the server if this dll is referenced. So unfortunately, nothing gets put on the server.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate your problem you must meet the following conditions. Since you want everything run in x64:

1.Make sure that you have installed 64-bit Oracle client software

2.Make sure that you using 64-bit `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` (use `corflags` to verify)

3.Make sure you build your application with x64 configuration

4.Disable `Enable 32 bit Application` on IIS pool

This is a common mistake by many people. They install 32-bit client and try to run x64 Oracle.DataAccess

Comment: As far as I can tell I am already doing all of the things you mention.

Comment: @philreed I've done it hundreds of times. Go over again and make sure! use `corflags`